# How to get MPMoviePlayerViewController current Playing time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to get current video playing time, not total duration.

My code is

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ((self.moviePlayer.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) {
        NSLog(@"content play length is %g seconds", self.moviePlayer.duration);
//        self.lblVideoDuration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.moviePlayer.duration];
    }
}
```

but above will give me total duration, but i don't want total duration.

if my Video duration is 1 minute and currently it play around 30 seconds, i want that live playback timing.

how can i get that?

I am able get Video Playback timing by start timer like this.

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (self.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        [self startDurationTimer];
    }
}

- (void)startDurationTimer {
    self.durationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(monitorMoviePlayback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopDurationTimer {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.durationTimer invalidate];
        self.durationTimer = nil;
    });
}

- (void)monitorMoviePlayback {
    double currentTime = floor(self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime);
    double totalTime = floor(self.moviePlayer.duration);
    double minutesElapsed = floor(currentTime / 60.0);
    double secondsElapsed = fmod(currentTime, 60.0);

    NSLog(@"Minute = %f && Second = %f", minutesElapsed, secondsElapsed);
    }
}
```

but when i call stoptimer method , Timer is not invalidating or not stopped.

how can i invalidate Timer?

Comment: Denny  check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option for you to use `AVPlayerViewController` instead of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, you can get current time from it via

```
myAVPlayerViewController.player.currentTime;
```

Although it is recommended to switch to AVPlayerViewController, as MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated, to get current time from MPMoviePlayerViewController, you can use following code:

```
self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. AVPlayer takes too much times to play, so i don't want to use that, can i fetch currenttime on MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: i updated my code. can you help me, why my timer is not invalidating?

Comment: have you checked if instance of `durationTimer` is non-nil when async block in `stopDurationTimer` method is called?

Comment: The point is that you might overwrite `self.durationTimer` every time when  `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification ` is called, and previous timer is still alive and ticking. You have to check for an already existing  instance of timer in `startDurationTimer` method, and, if it is already there, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Very perfect solution :-)

I created sample project and I worked out for your question.I got the solution.

**As MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated we need to use AVPlayerViewController.**

[Apple Document says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller?language=objc)

> The **MPMoviePlayerController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9**.
>   (**The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is also formally deprecated**.)
>   To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the
>   AVPictureInPictureController or **AVPlayerViewController** class from the
>   AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

So we must go with AVPlayerViewController or above one.Here I go with AVPlayerViewController.

I got the video play current time and duration.

> **First you need to add and import the AVKit and AVFoundation**

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;

- (IBAction)actionPlayVideoWithTime:(id)sender;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSURL *vedioURL;
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
    AVPlayer *playVideo;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize playerViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)actionPlayVideoWithTime:(id)sender {
    NSString *strVideoURL   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0034" ofType:@"MOV"];
    vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strVideoURL];
    playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:vedioURL];
    playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.player = playVideo;
    playerViewController.player.volume = 20;
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [playVideo play];
}


- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer {
    playerItem = playVideo.currentItem;
    CMTime totalDuration = playerItem.duration;
    NSTimeInterval currentDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.duration);
    NSLog(@" Capturing Duration :%f ",currentDuration);
    CMTime currentTime = playerItem.currentTime;
    int time = ceil(currentTime.value/currentTime.timescale);
    NSLog(@"time : %d",time);
    NSTimeInterval currentTimeNow = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem.currentTime);
    NSLog(@" Capturing Current Time :%f ",currentTimeNow);
}



@end
```

I have video file in my Bundle which name is IMG_0034.MOV

Please see the screenshot of my app and output.

See the play button

[image]

One I click the button it plays video below

[image]

Finally I print the current time and duration

[image]

Comment: i updated my code. can you help, why my timer is not invalidating?

Comment: reason for using MPMoviePlayerControlloer istead of AVPlayer is that, AVPlayer takes too much time for playing while MPMoviePlayerController instantly play Video.

Comment: No it is deprecated you must use AVPlayer